# Ubuntu 18.04 Kivy APK build is missing debug symbols

Tags: android, ubuntu, kivy, apk

I'm have an issue with my APK file in Android Studio where it is saying "Libraries (*.so) in the APK are missing debug symbols".  I have researched and haven't found solutions on this issue.  Does anyone have knowledge or experience as to what is causing this to occur and how to fix it?

Any thoughts and suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs because python-for-android simply doesn't build the libraries with debug symbols.

As it happens, a PR for this was merged recently, so debug symbols will now be present by default except in release builds. This feature is available in the develop branch and will be in the next release.

That said, unless you intend to actually debug an issue with the libraries (which would be unusual under non-development use), this doesn't really matter. Android Studio is telling you for general information, not because it's fundamentally a problem.

Comment: Hi inclement, thank you for the information.  The app crashes at start and I thought this was the reason.  I'll have to look into what may be going on.  Do you have any suggestions as to why it may happen?  The app is only requiring the normal and sqlite + requests because I have a small database in it

Comment: This will be nothing to do with why your app is crashing. You need to [debug it](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that and will now eliminate it from the equation.  Appreciate your help!